# How could I return an array from my module to my API using promise? Async Functions and Promise - Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, promise

I need to return a json object to my api. To do this I have a module that does some requests and should return the results.
My problem is grasping the promise concept and implementing it.

server.js

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res){
    request.getUsers()
    .then(function(users){
        console.log(users);
        res.contentType('application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify(users));
})
    .catch(function(){
    console.log(users);
    }); 
});
```

module.js

```
exports.getUsers = function(){
  var params = {search_string:""};
  var users  = [];

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      var result = connection.Users.get(params, function(error,response)
     {
      var user = [];
      for(let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++)
      {
        user = response.data;
      }
      users.push({user});
    });
    if(result != null)
    {
      console.log(result);
      resolve(result);
    }
    else
        {
        reject(new Error('Try Again'));
        }
    });
}
```

When I run the server I get the typeError: expecting a function but got [object object]

I did not really get what is wrong.

How could I return an array from my module to my API using promises?

EDIT:

```
 app.get('/users', function(req, res){
         request.getUsers()
         .then(function(users){
              console.log(users);
              res.contentType('application/json');
              res.send(JSON.stringify(users));
           })
         .catch(function(){
               console.log("not resolved");
          });
       });
```

My problem now is actually that I am getting the .catch even before any request is made the at /users endpoint and I dont know why.

Comment: Can you please indent your code so that we can understand it?

Comment: Please add full code files, who imports what, what is "connection" in the middle of "module". show us full context

Comment: What is `connection.Users.get`? Are you sure it returns a result?

Comment: That is my call to an external api. It works, but my problem is managing the promise so It will return users when the call is ready.

Comment: @Fix3r I have edited my answer to fix your second issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In module.js you used `new Promise()` constructor but the input parameter should be a function and not an object, so to fix that use:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var result = connection.Users.get(params, function(error,response)
    ...
});
```

Notice its not `new Promise({function(...)` but `new Promise(function(...)) ...`

Read more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Edit:
I have modified your code to work to fix the second problem:

```
exports.getUsers = function(){
  var params = {search_string:""};
  var users  = [];

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     var result = connection.Users.get(params, function(error,response) {

         if(error || !response)
         {
            // report error
            reject(new Error('Try Again'));
         }
         else
         {
            //process response
            var user = [];
            for(let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++)
            {
                user = response.data;
            }
            users.push({user});

            // report success
            resolve(users);
         }

    });

}
```

You need to call `resolve` or `reject` inside `connection.Users.get(params, function(error,response) {`

Comment: I did it, I get another problem though.
On the server.js it says that users is not defined.

     request.getUsers()
        .then(function(users){
            console.log(users);
            res.contentType('application/json');
            res.send(JSON.stringify(users));
      })

Comment: server.js catch statement should be something like this: `.catch(function(err) { console.log(err); }); ` and not printing users

Comment: Ah Ok, now I got it. Thanks for the link as well. I am trying not only to make it work but to really understand what is going on. I appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Thats great, Promises can be tricky to understand but very useful

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `module.js` code as below. You passed an object instead of a function.

```
    register.getUsers = function () {
      var params = { search_string: "" };
      var users = [];

      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var result = connection.Users.get(params, function (error, response) {
          var user = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            user = response.data;
          }
          users.push({ user });
        });
        if (result != null) {
          console.log(result);
          resolve(result);
        }
        else {
          reject(new Error('Try Again'));
        }
      });
    };
```

Comment: That completely ignores `users` though and always resolves immediately without waiting for the asynchronous callback.

Comment: That is the problem that appeared now.

Comment: The reason is `connection.Users.get(params, function (error, response) {` is an asynchronous call and doesn't wait for what goes inside this callback. Try executing this `response` array with Promise and handle your resolved state in `.then()` and reject state in `.catch()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

you declared user variable as an array and inside the for loop isn't useful because the user variable is always equals to response.data 
if response.data is array of JSON object you can push it to users array inside loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            users.push(response.data[i]);
        }
```

I guess you want to return the array of objects
also I recommend you to use bluebird module to return promises
and also you can use Promise.mapSeries instead of for loop like:

```
return Promise.mapSeries(response.data, item => {
                    users.push(item)
                })
```